# Creating Receipt Id for each Transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, excel

**Background**

I am using an Excel UI and VB ADODB back-end so users can insert data into SQL Server.

Since users are free to use as many rows as they would like (business requirement), I ended up using a `FOR` loop to iterate through the rows and insert them one by one.

**Initial Code**

```
        For i = 7 To LastRow

        Command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[TEP_Payments_Table] ([AA Number], " & _
     "[AA Name], [Request Receipt Id])" & _ 
"VALUES (" & _
"'" & Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(i, 2).Value & "'," & _
"'" & Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(i, 3).Value & "'," & _
"'" & Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(i, 6).Value & "')"

    Command.Execute
```

The 'Request Receipt Id' column is filled by Col6 in 'Project_Name' sheet. That was auto filled by by looking at the last id in `TEP_Payments_Table` and `+1`.

This resulted in duplicates if multiple users use it simultaneously.

I managed to get workout how to user `OUTPUT INSERTED` in a standard `INSERT INTO` clause to generate an id for each transaction; using the following syntax:

```
declare @ids table (id int);

insert into [dbo].[TEP_Payments_Table] ([col1], [col2]) 
    output inserted.id into @ids
    values ('testval1', 'testval2');
```

**Problem**

I am reluctant to add the `declare` and `output inserted` into the `for` loop, because I do not want it to do it for every line. I want a single id to be generated whether a user inserts 1 row of data, or 100 rows of data.

This is important as this receipt id will be used to track status of request.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: To clarify, do you want a single id for all the rows, or an id for each row?

Comment: @MathewPaxinos For all rows yes. One unique ID for each transaction. Each transaction can be n rows.